# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2kx}{k^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

> Find $S_1(x)$:
>   $$
> S_1(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2kx}{k^2}
> $$

My attempt:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Let } S_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2kx}{k^2}\\
&S_1+i\cdot S_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\cos x+i\sin x)^{2k}}{k^2}=[z=\cos x+i\sin x]=\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{k^2}=S\\
&\left(\frac{z^{2k}}{k^2}\right)'_z=\frac{2z^{2k-1}}{k}\\
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z^{2k-1}}{k}=\frac{2}{z}\sum_{k=1}^\infty
\frac{(z^2)^k}{k}=-\frac{2\ln(1-z^2)}{z}=T\ \ \ \ \ \ (|z|<1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then I tried to integrate $T$ (from $0$ to $z$) in order to get sum $S$. But this integral seems to get me back to the polylogarithm I was trying to avoid. So, I don't see how I can write $S_1$ with the finite number of terms (without the polylogarithm function).

Comment: Try expanding $x^2  - \pi x + \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6},\; 0 \le x \le \pi$ into a Fourier series.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) topic may interest.

Comment: @J.G.: very interesting (specially the [connection with Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_Bernoulli_polynomials) thanks for signalling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were on the right track.  Let $S(x)$ be given by the series $S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2kx)}{k^2}$.  Then, we see that for $x\in(0,\pi)$

$$\begin{align}
S(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2kx)}{k^2}\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2kx}}{k^2}\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\text{Li}_2(e^{i2x})\right)\\\\
&=\frac12 \left(\text{Li}_2(e^{i2x})+\text{Li}_2(e^{-i2x})\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac12\log^2(-e^{i2x})\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac14\left(2x-\pi\right)^2\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+x^2-\pi x
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Very nice!${}{}{}$

Comment: Could you explain how you found the results for the polylogarithms?

Comment: Yes.  [See the last identity in this article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Identities).

Comment: All right, thank you!

Comment: Okay, the last question: why do we have $+\frac{1}{4}(2x-\pi)^2$ in the next to last line if $\ln^2(-e^{2ix})=(2x-\pi)^2$

Comment: Without getting into the appropriate branch for the complex logarithm, we simply note that $-e^{i2x}=e^{i(2x+(2n-1)\pi)}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $\log(-e^{i2x})=i(2x+(2n-1)\pi)$.  Since we know that $S(0)=S(\pi)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we must choose $n=0$ and arrive at $\log(-e^{i2x})=2x-\pi$.

Comment: Yes, but the question was why do you have a "plus" sign before $\frac{1}{4}$ in the expression $\frac{-\pi^2}{12}+\frac{1}{4}(2x-\pi)^2$?

Comment: Recall that $i^2=-1$ so $-i^2=+1$

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

By "guessing" the appropriate function, we can find this sum with Fourier series.

First guess:

$$x^2 \sim \frac{\pi^2}{3} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\cos k x}{k^2}.$$

After guessing that the function is a parabola (quadratic in $x$), found the cosine series for:

$$f(x)=(x-a)^2, \textrm{ on the interval } \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$

It became apparent that $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ works.

[image]

$$f(x) \sim \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos 2 k x$$

$$a_0 = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2  \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

$$a_k = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \cos 2kx \, dx = \frac{1}{k^2}$$

$$\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 \sim \frac{\pi^2}{12} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2 k x}{k^2}.$$

So

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2 k x}{k^2} \sim \left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{12} .$$

The series is equal to the function on the right hand side in the interval $x \in (0,\pi)$, and its periodic extension, with period $\pi$.

Of course, this is the answer @Gary came up with in the comments.

Comment: Ah ... looks like @Gary has it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Could you explain how this formula helps? I mean it is different from what I am trying to calculate. The sum I'm trying to find doesn't have $(-1)^k$ inside.

Comment: Hi @Bonrey, The first posting was just a warm up to get started ...

Comment: good (+1), your results check with the link suggested by *J.G.* relative to the Clausen functions: re. in particular to the [connection with Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_Bernoulli_polynomials)

Comment: @GCab, Thank you!  What is this, then, $\pi^2 B_2 \left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)$?

Comment: yes right,  it is $SL_2(2x)= \pi^2 B_2 x/ \pi$ which a few lines below is given as $\pi^2 /6 -\pi x +x^2$, so a bit different from what you have computed .. you can recheck

Comment: @GCab, looks to be the same.  I've got it in the form $(x-h)^2+\alpha$.

Comment: ohps, sorry, it matches perfectly in fact ... I didn't catch that $1/4-1/12 =1/6$ .. :-(