# Find $f(x,y)$ from its Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I’m studying this question from Kröner: given $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\sin nx\sin ny.$$

I need to calculate $f(\frac{3\pi}{4},-\frac{5\pi}{4})$. I know I can brutally solve it by injecting the value into the series, but I’m trying to extract the function $f(x,y)$. I tried transforming the equation into something like $\cos n(x-y)-\cos n(x+y)$, and seperate $f$ into 2 functions of parameters $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$, but I’m stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed $2f(x,y)=g(x-y)-g(x+y)$, where $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}=s(x+\pi),\qquad s(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}.$$ The last series is well-known (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551734)). Another idea is that $s(x)$ and $g(x)$ are integrated [sawtooth waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave); there's a more general connection with [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series), also seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_Bernoulli_polynomials).

As a result, for $|x|\leqslant\pi$ we get $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$, thus $f(\frac{3\pi}{4},-\frac{5\pi}{4})=-\frac{\pi^2}{32}$.

Comment: For $|x-y|,|x+y|\le\pi$, I got $f(x,y)=\frac{-xy}{2}$, is my $f(x,y)$ correct?  I kept getting the same answer $\frac{-15\pi^2}{32}$, and I noticed that $x-y=2\pi\gt\pi$ in this case.

Comment: @KibiDango: Yes and yes [for our case we can use $g(2\pi)=g(0)$].